# Qt: define Tab Order programmatically

Tags: qt, symbian

I've created 2 widget with Desinger (Widget1 and Widget2) , each one has it's tab order defined.
A third widget (Widget3 )is defined programmatically and contains the above 2 widget in a vertical layout.
In on a symbian non touch device.
When I focus on widget3 I want to give the focus to widget1. Then go from widget1 to widget2 using the phone arrow when I reach the end of the widget1 tab chain.
What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 10):

From [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setTabOrder) for,

```
void QWidget::setTabOrder ( QWidget * first, QWidget * second )   [static]
```

which states that, *Puts the **second widget** after the **first widget** in the focus order.*

So for you, **the first widget** will be your `Widget3` and **second widget** will be your `Widget1`. (*if i understood the question correctly*)

Besides that, there are examples available regarding the usage of this function in the link I provided above. You can use it.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to take advantage of the default tab order by set by item construction order.
So just edit the .ui file XML:

```
<item>
     ... //Automatically assign with tab order X
</item>
<item>
     ... //Automatically assign with tab order X+1
</item>
```

In the order you wish the tab order to be.