# Set pattern in QLineEdits for tabs

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I have multiple `QLineEdit`-objects in my user interface, designed with QtDesigner. Now I want to set a pattern in which I can circle through them using the `tab`-key. Is that possible using code?

Comment: You can go through each lineedit with QWidget::setTabOrder() function.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: define Tab Order programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307758/qt-define-tab-order-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Designer provides a [tab order edit mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-tab-order.html), or you use [QWidget::setTabOrder()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder) to set it programmatically as @Ankur already said.